# Resizing a video player

Tags: pygame, vlc, resizable

I have pygame based video player, it has berkelium browser used for GUI,
under that are VLC libraries for playing streams. I did not make the player, but I would
like to add a "resize" option, which is not currently present.
The application is made for OS X.

On initialization of the player, `pygame.set_mode(screensize,OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)` is called, problem is when I resize the window more than the screen size, these parts are not visible(shown bugged), if I try `pygame.set_mode` again, it causes the app to crash because of dependencies (browser and VLC).

So I decided to initialize screen using:

`pygame.set_mode(screenresolution, OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)`

Which should set it to the max and then switch back to original, smaller resolution (like resize with the mouse).

How to do that? how to simulate the `RESIZABLE` flag and mouse move action?

The player works nice resizing to smaller sizes, it is only bigger sizes that are a problem.

```py
class InputAndDisplay:
    def init(self, fullscreen=False):
        global pygame, sys
        # if 'darwin' in sys.platform:
        #     import sys
        #     sys.argv = ['Core.py']
        #     import pygame.macosx
        #     pygame.macosx.init()

        pygame.init()

        global screenSize
        self.screenSize = screenSize
        if fullscreen:
            try: self.screenSize = pygame.display.list_modes()[0]
            except Exception, e: print e
            flags = OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF|FULLSCREEN
        else:
            flags = RESIZABLE|OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF

        print 'screenSize:', self.screenSize

        try:
            povrsina = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screenSize, flags)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            self.screenSize = screenSize
            povrsina = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screenSize, RESIZABLE|OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF)
        pygame.display.set_caption('NetTVBox-WebPlayer')

        pygame.mouse.set_pos(list(self.screenSize))
        if 'darwin' not in sys.platform:
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

        #pygame.key.set_repeat(300, 100)

        if 'darwin' not in sys.platform:
            pygame.mixer.quit()

        if 'linux' in sys.platform: # try to turn off vsyncing
            import ctypes
            libgl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libGL.so.1')
            proc = libgl.glXGetProcAddressARB('glXSwapIntervalMESA')
            _glXSwapIntervalMESA = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)(proc)
            _glXSwapIntervalMESA(0)

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        #gluPerspective(45.0, 640/480.0, 0.1, 100.0)
        glOrtho(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -5, 5)
        #glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.0)
        #glRotatef(25, 1, 0, 0)

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glShadeModel(GL_FLAT)
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glClearDepth(1.0)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)
        glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST)

        self.textures = glGenTextures(2)

        self.threeDmode = MODE_3D_OFF
```

that's `init` in `inputAndDisplay.py`
And main file is `Core.py` which calls it, and a lot of other stuff as well. Thats why I didnt put all the code here, there is a lot of it and not all important
Here is part of `Core.py`:

```py
input_and_display = InputAndDisplay()
input_and_display.init(self.fullscreen)
rc = RemoteControl()
rc.init()
media = Media()
if 1: # !
    media.config = {
        'buffering': state.mediaplayer_buffering,
        'contrast': state.mediaplayer_contrast,
        'saturation': state.mediaplayer_saturation,
    }
media.init()
browser = Browser()
browser.init()
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: share a bit more of the code.. preferably the init parts.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing the `VIDEORESIZE` event to detect resizing.

( See related events : `VIDEOEXPOSE`, `ACTIVEEVENT` http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html )

> http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode
>
> " Then the display mode is set, several events are placed on the pygame event queue. **pygame.QUIT** is sent when the user has requested the program to shutdown. The window will receive **pygame.ACTIVEEVENT** events as the display gains and loses input focus. If the display is set with the pygame.RESIZABLE flag, **pygame.VIDEORESIZE** events will be sent when the user adjusts the window dimensions. Hardware displays that draw direct to the screen will get **pygame.VIDEOEXPOSE** events when portions of the window must be redrawn. "

Comment: after many hours googling i found it kind of imposibile:)
* correction on line i sai that app crash on new set mode, it does not crash, sound and video stays in old context and new screen is black, i read a bit of opengl contextes, and thats my end, opengl contexts and stuf at this moment is a big bite for me, anyway thanks for help, and as for Videoresize event i didnt miss it just didnt put it.